# How do I find the default gedit color scheme xml files?

Tags: themes, gedit, colors

I know how to find new color schemes and alter them slightly to fit my liking. And I can make them slightly similar to the defaults.

What I want to do, however, is change one of the defaults slightly. To do that, I need the xml files of that scheme or some documentation on how to write a gedit color scheme.

Can someone point me to either the default scheme xmls or the documentation about them?

Answer (score 3):

The widget used by gedit is GtkSourceView. There is [documentation on the GNOME wiki](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GtkSourceView/StyleSchemes) for how to create style schemes, including where the files are located.

Comment: I can't find anything in the documentation relevant to how to create a gedit color scheme.

Comment: The page I linked to in the answer is exactly what you're looking for. GtkSourceView is the widget used by gedit.

Answer (score 1):

I found them in this location in Ubuntu 16.04:

```
/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles
```